# Static vs Object instantiation

Tags: java

I'm developing a website using struts2 framework.

I just need recommendations about when to use static methods and when to instantiate an object for a class.

For example:
in my database connection, I use a singleton so that there will only be one database connection for every user(is this correct?)
and I'm thinking if I have a class, let's say it is a class full of methods just for manipulating datas from a database. Should I make those methods static also? Or should I do make the class a singleton also so my app will only have one instance of the class full of methods?

Comment: Static is almost everytime a big problem in UnitTests

Comment: Your question is very general and vague, you won't get an answer if you don't provide more details.

Comment: Pick one and see how it works for you.  Next time pick the other.  This is how you learn.

Comment: "there will only be one database connection" may be true today, but not tomorrow. Use a DI framework to create one instance then inject it where it is needed, instead of "baking" it into your code with the Singleton anti-pattern.

Comment: ill give you very personal opinion, I needed to support nasty piece of code, where majority of methods were static. Believe me, it was hell on earth or even something worst. Hence, avoid statics if you can, they are good for utilities method bt thats all

Comment: generally static is used for so called "utils" classes. I would avoid static usage when possible.

Comment: Not an easy thing to answer. Academically speaking, if it's private (not needed to be tested) and does not use any instance state (variables, properties, other non static methods, etc) then you should use static which will give you a [very] small performance gain (avoiding to pass in the "this" reference and optional compiler optimization) but it's not always black and white. If your methods are public and need to be tested however, avoid static as much as you can since they're nasty to test (and will be impossible if you need to mock them).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answers :) I think it will be a big problem if I use static on my methods. I'll read more about them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are a good match for "pure functions": such pieces of code which don't depend on configured runtime state and have no side effects.

A method matching the above description can be easily unit-tested on its own because it doesn't have any dependencies which you would have to mock, and there is also no point in mocking its functioning.

Sometimes even functions fitting the above description may benefit from being instance methods of a utility object because that way polymorphism can be leveraged to override some of the behavior. Personally I have never had the need for that because those methods which I choose to implement as static are such that they have only one meaningful implementation.

Furthermore, *factory* methods are essentially required to be static because they are the ones which provide instances. Factory methods can be simple (some convenience around constructors) or have dependencies, especially on some configuration. In client code you can avoid heavyweight factory methods by relying on a Dependency Injection framework, but typically a standalone library will offer an entry point into its API by providing a static factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start talking about `static` and singletons in the context of a web app, you are now talking about concurrent access to the `static` / singleton thing, which is potential trouble in two ways:

- Not enough thread safety and you will have problems like illegal shared
  access (perhaps w/ your database connection), data corruption, race
  conditions, etc.
- Too much thread safety and you'll kill concurrency, with access to the shared `static` resource becoming the `synchronized` bottleneck for everything in your app

In general, you should avoid `static` in any multi-threaded environment (like a web app.)  The fact that your `static` thing is a database connection introduces additional issues, but also the solution.  Use a third party database connection pool like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/),  or similar.  Then you don't have to worry about managing either singleton-ness or concurrency at all.  The pool will be smart enough to take care of both.